# How do retrieve data from another dataframe in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 table:

First table

```
Course     Price 
English    $250
Chinese    $300
Math       $500
```

Second table:

```
Name       Course
Vivian     English
Vivian     Math
Shar       Math
Nick       Math
Tan        Chinese
```

I wish to have a code to get the table like this which the price column in second table is actually will refer to table one:

```
Name       Course      Price($)
Vivian     English     250
Vivian     Math        500
Shar       Math        500
Nick       Math        500
Tan        Chinese     300
```

Comment: You want to use pandas merge function

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge`:

```
table_2.merge(table_1, on='Course')
```

Output:

```
     Name   Course Price
0  Vivian  English  $250
1  Vivian     Math  $500
2    Shar     Math  $500
3    Nick     Math  $500
4     Tan  Chinese  $300
```